# How to Change Image Creation Date Based on Custom Ordering

Tags: photo-management

I use Google photo albums, which only has one sort option: sort by date. I usually want to display photos in a different, custom order. I'd like to rename a folder of images to X01, X02, X03, etc., and have the photos display by date in that same order. The exact time doesn't matter. I think as long as they are at least one minute apart, Google will sort them by date and therefore they'll be in the custom order that I want. Is there a program that will do this? I can use Adobe Bridge and Adobe Lightroom to change creation dates, but as a batch, they can only be shifted to earlier or later. I can't actually mix up the order. Thanks!

Comment: Plenty of applications will sort files by name, so it's just a matter of adding a prefix to your files names, like 001-, 002-, etc...

Comment: @xenoid Does that do any good if google albums does not have a "sort by file name" option? Or does google have a sort by file name option?

Comment: @xenoid Google does not have a 'sort by file name' option. I wish it did! I wouldn't have this problem in that case.

Comment: Then I would address the problem by the right end, change the application... or is it just that you need to create subfolders to keep some pics together?